Qual o significado e a classe gramatical de "lá", em "sei lá"?

Qual o significado e classe gramatical do "lá", na locução "sei lá"?
Qual a função sintática de "sei lá", como por exemplo na frase: "eu sei lá o que ele foi fazer em São Paulo."


O Priberam diz o seguinte:
lá
advérbio

Usa-se com valor expletivo, geralmente de negação e exclamação (ex.: eu sei lá do que é que ele está a falar! Mau, querem lá ver que ainda vamos ter de adiar a apresentação?).

Usa-se com valor expletivo, geralmente depois de um imperativo, para incitar a comunicação (ex.: olhe lá, não se distraia)


dicionario.priberam.org/l%C3%A1.
